# Comparable com Arrays.Sort

Tags: java, array

Estou tendo dificuldades na utilização da interface `Comparable`. Na classe `TrabalhoGA` devo chamar o método `ordenaPorPontos` da classe `temporada2013` que realiza a comparação de pontos dos `Pilotos` desta classe, preciso utilizar o `Arrays.sort` para organizar o array de pilotos. Ao rodar o `Arrays.sort` recebo o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at trabalhoga.porPontos.compare(porPontos.java:21)
>       at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:265)
>       at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:190)
>       at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
>       at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
>       at trabalhoga.temporada2013.ordenaPorPontos(temporada2013.java:49)
>       at trabalhoga.TrabalhoGA.main(TrabalhoGA.java:56)
>   Java Result: 1

Classe TrabalhoGA:

```
    Piloto[] pontuaram = new Piloto[30];

public void inserePilotosPontuados(String driver, String team, int points) {
    for(int i=0;i<getLast();i++){
        if(pontuaram[i].getDriver().equalsIgnoreCase(driver)){
            pontuaram[i].setPts(pontuaram[i].getPts()+points);
            return;
        }

    }
    pontuaram[getLast()] = new Piloto(driver, team, points);
}

private int getLast() {
int last = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < pontuaram.length; i++) {
    if (pontuaram[i] == null) {
        last = i;
        return last;
    }
}

return last;
}

public void ordenaPorNome(){  
    Arrays.sort(pontuaram,new porNome());  
}  

public void ordenaPorPontos(){  
    Arrays.sort(pontuaram,new porPontos());  
}  

public void gravar(File arquivo)throws IOException{  
    PrintWriter gravar = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(arquivo));  

    for (int i=0;i<pontuaram.length;i++){ 
        gravar.print(pontuaram[i]);  
    }
    gravar.close();  
}

public void mostraNaTela(){  
    int i = 0;
    while(pontuaram[i] != null && i<pontuaram.length){
        int numero = i+1;
        System.out.println("Classificado em "+numero+"° lugar:");
        System.out.println("Nome: "+pontuaram[i].getDriver());
        System.out.println("Equipe: "+pontuaram[i].getTeam());
        System.out.println("Pontos: "+pontuaram[i].getPts());
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Classe OrdenaPontos:

```
    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2){  
    Piloto p1 = (Piloto) obj1;  
    Piloto p2 = (Piloto) obj2;  

    if (p1.getPts() == p2.getPts())  
        return 0;  
    else if (p1.getPts() > p2.getPts())  
        return -1;  
    else  
        return 1;
```

> p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f54c08a, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@246972f1, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f54c08a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f93ee4, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@246972f1
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f93ee4, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f54c08a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f93ee4, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f54c08a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f93ee4
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@5c66b06b, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@5c66b06b, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@5c66b06b, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f93ee4
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@59c87031, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@59c87031, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@246972f1
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@59c87031, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f54c08a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@763dcf03, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@763dcf03, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@5c66b06b
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@763dcf03, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@53e20a9a, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@53e20a9a, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@763dcf03
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@53e20a9a, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@5c66b06b
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@1d262f7c, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@1d262f7c, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@53e20a9a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@1d262f7c, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@763dcf03
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@35f784d7, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@35f784d7, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@59c87031
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@35f784d7, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f54c08a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@35f784d7, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@d325aef, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@d325aef, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f54c08a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@d325aef, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@35f784d7
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@64f007ad, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@64f007ad, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@763dcf03
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@64f007ad, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@64f007ad, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@1d262f7c
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@4a8822a0, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@558fee4f
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@4a8822a0, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@6f54c08a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@4a8822a0, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@246972f1
>       at trabalhoga.porPontos.compare(porPontos.java:22)
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@2f995c9a, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@2f995c9a, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@59c87031
>       at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:265)
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@2f995c9a, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@4a8822a0
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@7d8e9adf, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@252cdd20
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@7d8e9adf, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@59c87031
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@7d8e9adf, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@4a8822a0
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@7d8e9adf, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@2f995c9a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@1d59e6df, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@35f784d7
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@1d59e6df, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@246972f1
>       at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:190)
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@1d59e6df, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@2f995c9a
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@1d59e6df, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@7d8e9adf
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@79444986, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@35f784d7
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@79444986, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@4a8822a0
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@79444986, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@7d8e9adf
>       at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
>   p1 = trabalhoga.Piloto@79444986, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@2f995c9a
>   p1 = null, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@d325aef
>       at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
>       at trabalhoga.temporada2013.ordenaPorPontos(temporada2013.java:49)
>       at trabalhoga.TrabalhoGA.main(TrabalhoGA.java:56)
>   Java Result: 1

Comment: O erro está claro: java.lang.NullPointerException. Abra sua classe porPontos.java (que provavelmente deve implementar java.lang.Comparable) e olhe com calma que provavelmente um dos dois parâmetros passados no metodo compare está null.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações na classe, mas ainda não consigo encontrar o erro.

Comment: Você está utilizando alguma IDE ? Na classe porPontos.java depois de `Piloto p2 = (Piloto) obj2;` coloque  `System.out.println("p1 = " + p1 + ", p2 = " + p2);` que antes de ele mostrar o erro, terá imprimido no console que uma das pessoas está null (não resolve seu problema que provavelmente deva ser algo com sua lógica, mas mostrará os dados antes de acontecer o NUllPointerException).

Comment: Editei no final dos codigos o erro que aparece quando insiro esse codigo.

Comment: Veja o que eu te disse: `p1 = null, p2 = trabalhoga.Piloto@d325aef`, p1 está null e você tenta no próximo comando if (p1.getPts() == p2.getPts()) sendo que p1 está null. Você precisa agora descobrir o porque de p1 estar null (bug no seu código) ou então para burlar essa mensagem, colocar um `if (p1 == null) { return 1; }` (eu não recomendo esta opção).

Comment: Eu estava instanciando 30 pilotos e só usando 18, por isso estava null. Arrumei esse numero e funcionou direitinho. Tks!

Answer (score 1):

porPontos.java:21

Uma variável referenciada na class porPontos.java, na linha 21, está null. Basta verificar ou mudar a lógica para garantir que não chegue aqui com valor null.